# LLVM | codegen for program entry function with command line options

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-c++-api

For my programming language, the entry of a program is like C/C++ `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return 0
}
```

**Suppose:**

- The IR code for `main` is generated into `llvm::Function`, using `llvm::IRBuilder`
- I have `llvm::LLVMContext` and `llvm::Module` created

**Question:**

If I want to compile this code into binary `prog`, how do use llvm to generate the part that passes the commandline arguments to `argc` and `argv` and then call `main`, which are provided by users when running `prog`?

Comment: If that function _actually_ is called main() and _actually_ has those arguments, then it should just work. If it isn't, then you'll need to generate a bridge function that actually is called main() and calls the function you want to be called, in the way you want it to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to arnt's comment:

> If that function actually is called main() and actually has those arguments, then it should just work. If it isn't, then you'll need to generate a bridge function that actually is called main() and calls the function you want to be called, in the way you want it to be called. – arnt

It works!